# WPF : adding a Button as "Show More" where on click of it would load remaining items in the itemControl which is already in Binding a Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am bit new to WPF (XAML) and I have an `ItemsControl` bound to a list with a `MyCollections` property . Now my requirement is initially to show only 1st element from the list and having a <kbd>Show More</kbd> button option at the end of list. A click on it would show the rest of the items from the collection.

This is my XAML so far, displaying the whole collection:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="ContentRoot" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollections}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding }" /> 
            <TextBox Text="{Binding }" />    
            </grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both a `ContentControl` (which displays the first item of the collection) and an `ItemsControl` (which displays the whole collection) displayed only when a `ToggleButton` is checked for example.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyCollection[0]}"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" Content="Show more"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggle, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can then adapt this to fit your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try the option